# access nginx x-accel request headers

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use X-Accel to pass information about the request to the internally redirected uri.

```
  location / {
      root /web/external;
      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/check.php;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/services/.sock/fastcgi.sock;
   }       
   location /internal/ {
      internal;
      alias /web/internal;
      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app.php;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/services/.sock/fastcgi.sock;
   }
```

The check.php returns an X-Accel-Redirect header to /internal/$uri and also sends other header values that i would like to pass over to the internal request. I have tried to access the headers using $sent_header_* but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a 3rd party module that seems to fit my use case more closely.  Though I wish it was something I could find "built in"

ngx_http_auth_request_module

http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/file/tip/README
http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_auth_request_module/file/tip/t/auth-request-set.t

The config would be changed to be like:

```
location / {
    auth_request /check;
    auth_request_set $value $upstream_http_x_value;
    add_header X-Set-Value $value;
    root /web/internal;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/app.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/services/.sock/fastcgi.sock;
 }       
 location /check {
    internal;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/check.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/services/.sock/fastcgi.sock;
 }
```